# After Android support libraries to 27.0.2 Xamarin app doesn't work in release mode only

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, release

After update my android support libraries to 27.0.2 and change the target to API 8.1,

Only in release mode, when the app runs, it starts and immediatly crashes...

I see in the device log

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Errors creating object graph:
>     java.lang.String has no injectable members. Do you want to add an injectable constructor? required by java.lang.String com.vungle.publisher.protocol.ProtocolHttpRequest$a.d
>       at dagger.internal.ThrowingErrorHandler.handleErrors(ThrowingErrorHandler.java:34)
>       at dagger.internal.Linker.linkRequested(Linker.java:182)
>       at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.getInjectableTypeBinding(ObjectGraph.java:309)
>       at dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.inject(ObjectGraph.java:280)
>       at com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase.a(vungle:171)
>       at com.vungle.publisher.VunglePub.a(vungle:27)
>       at com.vungle.publisher.VunglePubBase.init(vungle:88)
>       at com.vungle.publisher.VunglePub.init(vungle:43)
>       at com.movile.android.maisapps.MaisAppsApplication.onCreate(MaisAppsApplication.java:127)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1020)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5007)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1483)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

when I rebuild:

```
The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 
'Android.Widget.AutoSizeTextType 
Android.Support.V4.Widget.IAutoSizeableTextView::get_AutoSizeTextType()' in 
assembly: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.dll' ---> 
Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve Android.Widget.AutoSizeTextType
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedType(TypeReference reference)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessEntireQueue()
at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
 at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
 at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()    neoFly_Montana.Android
```

Can someone help? 
it's only in release mode...

Comment: Seems like its an issue with Dagger. used dagger?

Comment: I don't know what it is...I am working with xamarin.forms

Comment: In the release mode, try to set the [Linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker) to None in your Android Options.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found that the version of Mono.Android.dll that was my project was referencing was incorrect. Changing this version to the correct version, which matched the Target Framework version of the project resolved the rebuild issue for me.
The correct version for my project was located here on my machine :-
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v8.1\Mono.Android.dll